# Как узнать значения аргументов функции, которое ей передали?

Tags: python-3.x, функции

Есть такое задание:

- Написать декоратор, который будет логировать (записывать в лог файл) ошибки из декорируемой функции и выбрасывать их дальше.
- Имя файла лога - function_errors.log
- Формат лога: <имя функции> <параметры вызова> <тип ошибки> <текст ошибки>
- Лог файл открывать каждый раз при ошибке в режиме 'a'

вот мое решение:

```
def log_errors(func):
    def suragate(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        except Exception as exp:
            with open('function_errors.txt', 'a') as file:
                log_string = f'<{func.__name__}><{type(exp)}><{exp}><{exp.args}>\n'
                file.write(log_string)
            print(exp)

    return suragate
```

**Но, я не понимаю, как в строке лога, после имени функции, получить параметры вызова?**

Comment: `log_string = f'<{func.__name__}><{args}><{kwargs}><{type(exp)}><{exp}><{exp.args}>\n'` и вместо print(exp) поставьте raise

Comment: спасибо большое!)